# DatePicker issue in android 4.1 and 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, datepicker, android-datepicker

I am developing an android app for all the versions (version 2.2 to 4.2). I am using datePicker in it and changing the color of selected date to white using following code:

```
if (currentapiVersion >= 14) {

    ViewGroup dayChildpicker = (ViewGroup) datePicker
            .findViewById (Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android"));
    ViewGroup monthChildpicker = (ViewGroup) datePicker
            .findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android"));
    ViewGroup yearChildpicker = (ViewGroup) datePicker
            .findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android"));

    EditText dayET = null;
    EditText mornthET = null;
    EditText yearET = null;

    dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.getChildAt(1);
    mornthET = (EditText) monthChildpicker.getChildAt(1);
    yearET = (EditText) yearChildpicker.getChildAt(1);

    dayET.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // null pointer error on this line
    mornthET.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    yearET.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

But this is throwing null pointer exception in android 4.1 and 4.2(Jelly beans) at the line

```
dayET.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

In Jelly beans, I am not getting Edit text view in datepicker.

What is the method to get childs of date picker in jellybeans and how to change text color of selected date in date picker.

Please guide me.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace and point out which line of code you get the NPE?

Comment: Hi Kirk, I am getting NPE at dayET.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); In jelly bean dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.getChildAt(1); this code does not return any EditText view. I do not know why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `getChildAt(1)` actually gets the control since there may be no guarantee what order a control is in the `ViewGroup`. However you should be able to reference these differently through an identifier

Change these

```
dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.getChildAt(1);
mornthET = (EditText) monthChildpicker.getChildAt(1);
yearET = (EditText) yearChildpicker.getChildAt(1);
```

To these

```
dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id",  "android"));
mornthET = (EditText) monthChildpicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id",  "android"));
yearET = (EditText) yearChildpicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id",  "android"));
```

This should allow you to reference these properly without a null pointer error.

Let me know if you have other questions or it doesn't work.

Comment: The above code does not work. It is throwing NPE at the same line. Now in Android 4.0 as well as 4.2

Comment: Hmm. Try one last time by replacing `timepicker_input` with `numberpicker_input`. If not you may be forced to create your own `DatePicker` widget to expose the `EditText` widgets. Code for this is at <http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java#95>

Comment: Thanks. numberpicker_input resolves the NPE, but in ANdroid 4.2, text color of selelcted date does not turns to White, it changed to default color (Black). I also did this by using seperate conditions for 4.0 and 4.2. For 4.0 I used dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.getChildAt(1); and for 4.2 I used dayET = (EditText) dayChildpicker.getChildAt(0); This also do not throw NPE but in 4.2 it returns object but not of EditTeXt view. In your case this problem is same. I am not getting why android 4.0 OS retuns EditText object but Android 4.2 doest not retuns EditText object?

Comment: They may have changed the way you can access the private controls in 4.2 and I know this way is not guaranteed to work in the future. I'd suggest creating your own version of the widget and expose the `EditText` of each field to be accessible. This will prevent the need to have different code paths for different Android versions